# Как отключить режим "Картинка в картинке" на видео Wordpress HTML5

Tags: html, wordpress, видео, elementor

уважаемые участники сообщества!

При просмотре видео страницы через Firefox (с компьютера) и браузера iphone появляется контекстное меню, позволяющее просмотреть видео в отдельном окне («картинка в картинке»).
Если нажать на контекстное меню «картинка в картинке», то видео из блока пропадает, оставляя весь блок пустой. Я не хочу, чтобы на странице с видео пользователь мог это сделать (случайно или намеренно).

Пример: [секция с видео фоном](https://ibb.co/HxgTCRr) / [секция «картинка в картинке»](https://ibb.co/y6K39Pp)

Прошу вас подсказать возможное решение, чтобы исключить любое вмешательство со стороны браузеров к видео. Как отключить режим «Картинка в картинке» для видеоэлемента?

Я нашел несколько подходов к устранению, но понять, как их внедрить не хватает технических знаний:

1. Об использовании атрибутов [disablePictureInPicture](https://w3c.github.io/picture-in-picture/#disable-pip).
2. Apple [avpictureinpicturecontroller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller).

Comment: Это поведение браузера. И даже если это  возможно, то менять поведение браузера не нужно. Пользователь сам разберётся как ему лучше смотреть.

Comment: Это "поведение" можно контролировать, используя атрибут disablePictureInPicture (https://w3c.github.io/picture-in-picture/#disable-pip или https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/requestPictureInPicture). Технически, у меня не хватает навыков, поэтому я попросил помощи, если кто-то сталкивался с подобным.